# Prometheus-Grafana : How to use wildcard in query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, microprofile

I have below labels in prometheus, how to create wildcard query while templating
something like “query”: “label_values(application_*Count_Total,xyx)” . These values are generated from a Eclipse Microprofile REST-API

```
application_getEnvVariablesCount_total
application_getFEPmemberCount_total
application_getLOBDetailsCount_total
application_getPropertiesCount_total
```

```
  {
    "allValue": null,
    "current": {
      "isNone": true,
      "selected": false,
      "text": "None",
      "value": ""
    },
    "datasource": "bcnc-prometheus",
    "definition": "microprofile1",
    "hide": 0,
    "includeAll": false,
    "label": null,
    "multi": false,
    "name": "newtest",
    "options": [
      {
        "isNone": true,
        "selected": true,
        "text": "None",
        "value": ""
      }
    ],
    "query": "microprofile1",
    "refresh": 0,
    "regex": "{__name__=~\"application_.*Count_total\"}",
    "skipUrlSync": false,
    "sort": 0,
    "tagValuesQuery": "",
    "tags": [],
    "tagsQuery": "",
    "type": "query",
    "useTags": false
  },
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prometheus treats metric names the same way as label values with a special label - `__name__`. So the following query should select all the values for label `xyx` across metrics with names matching `application_.*Count_total` regexp:

`label_values({__name__=~"application_.*Count_total"}, xyx)`

Comment: can you please show me how the json out would like ? I have edited the question with a output

Comment: Just put the string in `query`. Something like the following: `"query": "label_values({__name__=~\"application_.*Count_total\"}, xyx)"`

Comment: Gettting error

Template variables could not be initialized: parse error at char 12: unexpected character inside braces: '\\'

Comment: Note the `.` is very important. Was doing `...=~"search term*"` and didn't work. Just need to make sure it was `.*`. Example: `{job_name=~"watcher-job-.*"}`

Answer (score 4):

@valyala, I got it working with

```
"query": "metrics(application_get.*Count_total)",
"regex": "/application_get(.*)Count_total/",
```

Answer (score 4):

In my Promql, this worked for me:

```
topk(5, {__name__=~"thing_you_want_to_search.*"})
```

which finds the first 5 lines that matches the `thing_you_want_to_search*`